# Creating a new project from exported template in VS doesn't bring in any code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, project

I have exported templates for WPF projects plenty of times in the past with success - Right now I have a dotnet core 2 console app (C#).

I've exported a project template within VS, and the output looks similar to any other WPF project I have exported, the .vstemplate file looks correct.

I create a new project in VS using the exported dotnet core 2 template, but all it brings in is the dependencies. It brings in no folders, no code, etc.

I see no errors etc, however I also don't have a properly imported project...On left is the solution explorer of a new project created using the template, and on the right is some of the contents of the .vstemplate, showing that there are missing files it should be bringing in. Those files are also present within the exported template.

[image]

for reference, The name of the exported project is BinanceBase (on the right) and on the left is the new project, BinanceCandleScraper.

Comment: Try manually adding in each item by right clicking the project and clicking "Add Existing Item". They close it and re open to see if that solves your problem!

Comment: There's quite a large number of files missing, and also that wouldn't do things such as renaming the namespaces accordingly etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem with .NETCore project templates in the current version of VS2017.  The primary bug report [is here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/155961/customer-net-standard-project-template-does-not-lo.html).  Fwiw, developercommunity.visualstudio.com is always the site you want to search first whenever you encounter VS2017 issues.

Chasing the links lands you on [Iris Classon's web page](http://irisclasson.com/2017/06/14/visual-studio-2017-templates-and-the-missing-content/), she diagnosed the underlying problem.  And discovered the workaround, you have to edit the project template by hand.  Inside the `<TemplateData>` element, you have to edit:

```
   <CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
```

Credit to Iris for figuring this out, I can't tell how she did it.

Comment: She compared the template files with a Visual Studio example.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, and solved the problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: Still true for VS2022. Thanks for figuring this out